# IOS received notification when not connected bluetooth device is no longer available

Tags: iphone, ios, core-bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I know how to received new available peripheral notification using `scanForPeripheralsWithServices` used with its callback `didDiscoverPeripheral` to populate a `UITableView` list.

But, how to receive notification when the **not connected** Bluetooth devices is no longer available?

```
/****************************************************************************/
/*                              Discovery                                   */
/****************************************************************************/
- (void) startScanningForUUIDString:(NSString *)uuidString
{
    NSArray         *uuidArray  = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:uuidString], nil];
    NSDictionary    *options    = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey];

    [centralManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:uuidArray options:options];
}

- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    if (![foundPeripherals containsObject:peripheral]) {
        [foundPeripherals addObject:peripheral];
        [discoveryDelegate discoveryDidRefresh];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume the reason your wondering is because you would like to refresh your `foundPeripherals` array and update UI correct? Well since you have no current bond with the device there is no way to know when the device has moved away or come closer. Your solution is this: start an NSTimer that clears your `foundPeripherals` and begin discovering again when it fires. If you see it in the new discovery, it's still there and you should re-add to `foundPeripherals`. Otherwise it's gone.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am already do that as workaround. I am a bit surprise that there is no way to be notified when a device is no longer available.

Comment: Yeah maybe with ios 7 though..hopefully

Comment: Doyou know if IOS7 implement this functionnality?

Comment: for this solution, will you have to set the option 'CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey' to YES?   also it seems there is no alternate solutions for iOS 7.